# Asp.net Session Url Asp.net Page.IsPostBack getuserinfo error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url, session, authentication

Okay,The Other errors are fixed now im at this point where my other pages need their code to be updated:

Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 public partial class Controls_GetUserScraps : System.Web.UI.UserControl

{

DataBaseClass dbClass = new DataBaseClass();
public DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString()));
    }
}
public void GetUserScraps(int Id)
{
    string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.FirstName,,u.LastName,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [User] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "'";
    dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I replaced Session ID to UserId and it removed the error now it has displayed another error under.

Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[image]

```
string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as       UserId,u.FirstName,,u.LastName,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [User] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" +   Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "'";
```

Adding your fix created this new error:
[image]

Comment: Does `ctlLogin.UserName` contain the name you would like to redirect to or do you need to do a database lookup to get tha actual user name?

Comment: yeah ,You need to do a database look up to get the actual user name.

Comment: Is there a particular error message you are getting with that latest edit? Does that page you are redirecting to exist?

Comment: Yes the Home.aspx exists and The error is +  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: You aren't redirecting to the home page, you are redirecting to `Home.aspx/UserName' (this isn't necessarily causing the error, I just thought I'd point it out). The reason you are getting that error is because you are trying to parse a value from the query string that is no longer there.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. You won't be able to parse an integer from `Home.aspx/UserName', so you may need to rethink how methods like `GetUserDetails` and `GetUserFriends` work.

Comment: then why did it work with Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?Id=" + Session["UserId"].ToString()); and loaded all of the logged in users data from the database?

Comment: The `Session` is very different from the query string. The query string consists of a bunch of key/value pairs after the `?` in a url, the `Session` is stored on the server either in memory or a database. Try this: if the `UserId` is in the session, call `GetUserDetails(int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString());` and the `GetUserFriends` method in the same way. That should do the trick.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `GetUserFriends` method? Based on your existing code, you would invoke it as `GetUserFriends(int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString());`

Comment: Easy one: in your `GetUserScraps` method, that first line of code is still trying to use the value `Id` from the query string. The fix is to simply use the `Id` parameter you passed to that method.

Comment: i got the same errors with Id

Comment: how would i combined    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName")%>  And
                                 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName")%>

Comment: In that error message, you are parsing trying to parse `Session["Id']`: this should be `Session["UserId"]`. For your other question, try this: `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName").ToString() + " " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName")%>`

Comment: That image is too narrow to see the whole line. Would you be able to update your code with any changes? If the code is the same, then the fix is to use the `Id` parameter in the `GetUserScraps` method rather than parsing the id from the query string.

Comment: The fix is to use the Id parameter in the GetUserScraps method rather than parsing the id from the query string. Like this: `string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as       UserId,u.FirstName,,u.LastName,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [User] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" + Id + "'";`

Comment: There are two commas after `u.FirstName` - remove one of them.

Comment: Thank you , The home.aspx page shows up after login, however the users information from the database didnt show up  on the page except the  FirstName and LastName.  I think it has to do with UserId and Id

Comment: It might pay to split that out into another question (I can help with that one too, if you need it). If I have answered your original question then it would be great if you would accept my answer.

Comment: okay Usually Lastlogin, About User  and User Image is stored and displayed when they login. However now after changing the web site's code it now only displays the FirstName and LastName. So i think something is preventing website to retrieve info about the logged in user. (UserId or Id)

Comment: I would need to see some code for that - create a new question and I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to have the `private bool UserAuthenticate` method take an `out` parameter which you can use to return the actual user name from the database.

```
private bool UserAuthenticate(string UserName, string Password, out string actualUserName) 
{ 
    actualUserName = string.Empty;

    bool boolReturnValue = false; 
    //-------------------------------- 
    //Check UserID From Config File 
    if (UserName == "User" && Password == "Pass") 
    { 
        boolReturnValue = true; 
        return boolReturnValue; 
    }     
    else 
    { 
        //-------------------------------- 
        dt = new DataTable(); 
        string chkUser = "Select * FROM [User] where Email='" + UserName + "' AND Password='" + Password + "'"; 
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(chkUser); 
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
        { 
            //TODO: grab the actual user name from the row and assign it to actualUserName. For example:
            actualUserName = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"];

            boolReturnValue = true; 
            Session["UserId"] = dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString(); 
            string updateLastLogin = "Update [User] SET LastLogin='" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "' where Id='" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + "'"; 
            dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(updateLastLogin); 
        } 
        return boolReturnValue; 
    } 
}
```

After that you would then need to do something like this in the `OnAuthenticate` method:

```
string actualUserName;
Authenticated = UserAuthenticate(ctlLogin.UserName, ctlLogin.Password, out actualUserName);
```

And the redirect would now be:

```
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx/" + actualUserName);
```

Comment: i only FullName not firstname and lastname so how would i change actualUserName = string.Format("{0} {1}", dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"], dt.Rows[0]["LastName"]); to become only retrieve  FullName

Comment: How's this: `NameLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString(), dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString());`

Comment: i added the full line with no changes.